# How do I open an existing django project in LiClipse?

Tags: django, pydev, liclipse

Really dumb question, but it's taking me too long to figure out how to open an existing django project "mysite" in LiClipse (mysite wasn't created within LiClipse). I tried import and wasn't seeing anything obvious, I tried creating a new project (file>new>project... )with the "Use default" setting unchecked (and browsed to the mysite home directory) but it still created a new project instead of loading mysite. If I browse to each individual file in mysite I can open them in LiClipse but I want mysite to be recognized by LiClipse as a django project.

If anyone with some experience using LiClipse and Django can take a few minutes to walk me through it I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way in this case is creating as a regular PyDev project (which won't create any new files -- i.e.: file > new > project...) and then right-clicking the created project and selecting `PyDev > Set as Django project`.

Comment: btw i absolutely love LiClipse/PyDev!